# Call to undefined method App\Product::link()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, laravel-4

Help me, i am trying put some pagination in my page, but keep showing this error **Call to undefined method App\Product::link()**

my Code

Blade:

```
@extends('layouts.index')
@section('content')

<!-- TOP Navbar -->
<div class="w-100 shadow d-flex position-relative position-fixed" style="z-index: 2; background-color: white; ">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center py-3 mr-auto" style="width: 200px">
        <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="logo icon">
    </div>

    <div class="pt-4 bd-highlight"><a href="/">
            <a href="/create">
                <button type="button" class="btn font p-auto rounded-pill text-white font-weight-bold "
                        style="background-color: #28AD47; width: 178px; height: 40px">New Product
                </button>
            </a>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class=" bd-highlight">
        <div class="dropdown px-5" style="padding-top: 24px">
            <a class=" align-middle font dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
               style="color: #2c3539">                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}

            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu mt-4" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" x-placement="bottom-start"
                 style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(-20px, 38px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/profile') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                   onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    Logout
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-------------------------->

<div style="background-color: #F8F8F8; z-index: 0;" class="d-flex justify-content-start ">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: calc(100vh - 70px);margin-top: 73px;z-index: 1"
         class="bg-white shadow position-fixed ">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="/create">
                <p class="font my-5" style="color: #525252"><img src="/images/plus.svg" class="mr-3" alt="plus icon"
                                                                 width="16px" height="16px">
                    New Product
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <p class="font my-5" style="color: #525252"><img src="/images/edit.svg" class="mr-3" alt="edit icon"
                                                             width="16px" height="16px">
                Edit Product
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-100 " style="margin-top: 73px;margin-left: 200px">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h1 class="font p-5">All products</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- <div style="height: calc(100vh -  202px);background-color: #676767">-->
        <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
            @foreach($products as $product)
                <div class="product shadow m-4">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                        <img src="/images/car-example.png" alt="car photo" width="190px" height="140px">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <p class="font text-white pt-4 pl-5" style="font-size: 16px">
                            {{$product->name}} <img src="/images/info.svg" alt="info icon" width="20px"
                                                     height="15px" class="pl-2 mb-1 red-tooltip"
                                                     data-toggle="tooltip"
                                                     data-placement="right" title="{{$product->description}} ">
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-flex  bd-highlight" style="margin-top: 40px">
                        <div class="pl-5 mt-auto bd-highlight">
                            <h3 class="font text-white">${{$product->price}}</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="bd-highlight ml-auto mt-3 pr-5">

                            <a href="/">
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="btn font rounded-pill text-white font-weight-light "
                                        style="font-size: 18px;background-color: #28AD47; width: 99px; height: 41px">
                                    Buy
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            @endforeach

        </div>

        <div class="w-100" style="background-color: white; z-index: 0;">
            <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center pt-2">
                    {{ $product->link() }}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>





<!-- Bootstrap Link -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

        })
    </script>

    <!-- Hover -->


 @endsection
```

Controller:

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()

```
{
    $products = Product::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
    return view('show')->with('products', $products);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */



public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' =>'required | unique:product|max:64',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);


    print_r($request->input());
    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->description = $request->description;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    echo $product->save();

    return redirect('/home');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{

}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('home', 'ProductController');

Route::get('profile', 'UserController@profile')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('profile', 'UserController@update_avatar')->name('profile');

Route::view('create', 'create')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('submit', 'ProductController@store');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use products and links in plural

```
<div class="w-100" style="background-color: white; z-index: 0;">
        <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center pt-2">
                {{ $products->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Worked, thanks very much!!! i am new in laravel! thank you very much